# Angular 9 animation - how to animate individual destruction of components without wrapping them in a new div?

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

Is it necessary to wrap a component in an element (like div) that has @animation on itself in order to animate the destruction of that component? Here's what I tried so far: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/understanding-angular2-animations?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Basically, I want this:

```
<my-component @anim *ngIf="show" (click)="toggleShow()"></my-component>
```

instead of this:

```
<div @anim *ngIf="show">
    <my-component (click)="toggleShow()"></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: The `div` wrapper is required here because the animations apply to the elements that are bound to. So the `div` tag will be created initially and animated in and out of view by Angular.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, `<my-component>` is also an element and it is not animated correctly when an animation is placed on it together with `*ngIf`

Comment: Applying the animation directly to the component also doesn't seem to work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/understanding-angular2-animations-jfzvbe .Your best bet is probably to use a wrapper.